# How Do I Remove Duplicated From "This PC"?

Tags: windows-10, duplicate

As seen in the screenshot, "*This PC*" shows double "*Desktop*" Icons and missing the "*Downloads*" folder.

How do I get rid of the duplicate and restore the downloads folder?

[image]

Comment: Fix the Shell Folders registry values. [Shell Folders Like Music and Videos Merged and Pointing to Same Folder](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/shell-folders-merged-music-videos-same-folder/)

Comment: The second entry is likely pointed towards ELION can you confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please first check the target of the download folder (right now, it
   is 'Desktop'), by right clicking and opening up properties. If the
   target is something like 'C:\Users\YourUserNameHere\Downloads', then
   everything is fine. If not, we may have to dig little more deeper than this.
2. If you or someone else, has renamed the folder to 'Desktop', and changed the icon, you just have to rename the folder in favorites and change the icon. Just right click on the name and select 'Rename' from the context menu.
3. Right click the folder and open up the properties. To change icon, click the **Shortcut** tab and next, **Change Icon...**.